# how to create jar file with embedded database H2?

Tags: java, database, javafx, jar, h2

I have created javaFX project with embedded database H2. And I have created jar. On my computer this programm works. And on other computer this programm runs but buttons doesn't work. I think they dont work because project doesn't see database. I cant understand how to build project right with dependencies(database). Plz help me to build jar with database!!
P.S. I dont know how to use maven.

Comment: debugging tip: 1. do a recursive comparison (e.g. recursive diff of the files / directory hierarchy after expansion of any zip/jar/etc) of the version that works with the version that doesn't. 2. if you find the version that doesn't is missing a file (or files plural) then your hypothesis sounds promising that it's missing a file for the db. Then you can rectify it (if that's the case) by making sure the code that you distribute (whether it's a jar, zip, or a thumb drive with a directory of the files, or whatever) contains that missing file or files.

Comment: There are so many reasons your application may work on one computer but not on another, that it is hard to advise.  You may wish to bundle and deploy your application using [self-contained application packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).  Information on why you may (or may not) wish to do this and how to do so is contained in the linked documentation.  [Makery also provide a deployment tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/) that includes local storage (a file not a db, but similar concept).

Comment: You do realise by embedding the do you won't be able to write to it

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution to the root cause of your problem, but to include a database in a jar file can be done in the following way:

**Theory**: Execute a script that creates and populates the database when the application starts. This should be done only once, on the first execution. Further executions should use the existing database and data.

**How To**: use [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or another tool to executes the script automatically calling a simple method.